# Cannot move files into USB; owner is root.

Tags: usb, root

Long story short, I am using Tails because I was reinstalling my mac OS on my USB and I forgot two files I now have, anyways when I moved them into the USB I get an error that I do not have sufficient premissions to do so.

I researched it, but it seems these things have been done on a case-by-case basis and so I could not find ultimately a solution that would work for me.

If someone would be ever so kind as to help me that'd would be awesome

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Off topic because it's not about Ubuntu but Tails. Please ask your question on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the USB drive is unproperly mounted (with the wrong permissions). If you are auto-mounting, this shouldn't happen. You can try manually mounting anyway. Check out this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB.

Comment: I read a similar thing that said it could be this way because I created in Mac OSX with a root user which could have caused the premissions to change/owner to change. Is there anyway I could undo this and change it to me?

Comment: I am not sure of how ownership works on a portable volume, you could try changing the owner: 

`cd path_to_usb` and then 
`sudo chown -hR username:username .`

Comment: How do I find the username? this is a live boot of tails?

Comment: it would be your username, as it shows up when you type `whoami` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

1. `sudo su`
2. then
   `nautilus`
   **Or**
   `sudo mv "file adress here" "destination here"`
   in the terminal.

Comment: alright let me try that, will comment with results

Comment: brilliant my friend, it was completely successful.

Comment: nevermind i get 
"mv: inter-device move failed: '/home/amnesia/Desktop/BaseSystem.dmg to '/media/OSX Base System/BaseSystem.dmg'; unable to remove target: Red-only file system

Odd, it worked with my other file

Comment: It still says "read only file system"

Comment: Or try changing file permissions with "sudo chmod 111 /home/amnesia/Desktop/BaseSystem.dmg" and then try again.

Comment: It still says "read only file system", I think we got to change the owner of the USB. Is there anyway I could just view my mac created usb on windows and just drop the file there? When I plug it into my other PC i get "efi" and it only has 192mb space. I am using tails for it because it seems to be the only one that can read this file system besides mac os.

Comment: To change device permissions try "mount -o rw,remount /dev/<devicename> /path/of/device/mount/directory"

Comment: Should I put the command in like this: mount -o rw,remount /dev/OS X Base System '/media/OS X Base System'

Comment: No.After /dev it should be something like sda1 or others.Check gparted or disks to see your device name.The part after /media is OK.And use sudo before mount.

Comment: did it, but no luck I think. Should I just get a virtual box on my windows machine and then try to put files in it that way?

Comment: Maybe try that.